# Is this valid as it is naturally occurring?

Tags: us6431498

Scalloped wing leading edges are found naturally on hump back whales which use them for all the reasons described in this patent. Is this not considered prior art?

http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US6431498

Comment: Linking to the patent in question would be quite  helpful.

Comment: Sorry, first time I used this site. I thought it linked it automatically. I just added it.

Comment: Last time I looked, humpback whales neither had wings nor used them for lift when flying. The priority date on this patent is June 30, 2000 and the issue COULD be raised that leading edge flaps DID exist before Y2K. You could rephrase the question accordingly?

Comment: My wording may not be quite right, but I would argue that the leading edge of a whale fin gives it lift for flying through water. They give it higher manoeuvrability and all the other traits described in the patent. The only difference is the matter that they are flying through but is that enough to make a patent on it?